# How to get index of iframe in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm working on an extension that collects clicks from a page.

I've a script that on each click report back (to the background.js) the x/y coordinates of the click. I'm not sure on how to get the index of the iframe that send the message back to the background.js.

I know selenium IDE/Katalon.. does it, but I'm not sure how they managed to do that.

Any idea is welcomed, thanks.

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "testi",
  "homepage_url": "http://woop.weep",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [
      "http://*/*",
      "https://*/*"],
    "js": [
      "content_frame.js"
      ],
    "match_about_blank": true,
    "all_frames": true
  }],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "woop!"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "https://*/*",
    "http://*/*",
    "tabs",
    "system.display"
  ]
}
```

background.js:

```
    console.log("BACKGROUND");

    let data = {baseUrl: false, actions: [], display: false};

    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
            file: 'inject.js'
        });
    });


    chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener( function(activeInfo) {
        console.log("Changed tab to ",activeInfo);
        console.log("got recorded user action");
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(activeTab){
            console.log("activeTab: ",activeTab);
            data.actions.push({type:"userAction", action: "switchTab", tabUrl: activeTab[0].url, tabIndex: activeTab[0].index});
            console.log("data.actions after switch tab: ",data.actions);
        });
    });


    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
        function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
            console.log("request: ",request);
            console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
            if (request.type == "userAction"){
                    console.log("got recorded user action");

                if (request.action=="click"){
                    let lastAction = data.actions[data.actions.length-1];
                    console.log("PRE EPOCH CHECK");
                    console.log("request: ",request);
                    console.log("lastAction: ",lastAction);
                    if (lastAction && request.epoch -lastAction.epoch< 2){
                        console.log("Got a double click, merge previous event with the new one");
                        data.actions[data.actions.length-1].action = "doubleClick";
                        request = data.actions[data.actions.length-1];
                    }
                    else{
                        data.actions.push(request);
                    }
                }

                console.log("collected data: ",data);
                sendResponse({feedback: request, data: data});
            }
        });
```

content_script:

```
    function sendMessageToExtension(messageObj){
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(messageObj , function (response) {
            if (response) {
                console.log("got a response: ",response);
            } else {
                console.log("no response from extension");
            };
        });
    }



    console.log("WOOOOOOOOOOOP "+ window.location.href);

    (function() {
        document.onmousemove = handleMouseMove;
        function handleMouseMove(event) {
            var eventDoc, doc, body;
            event = event || window.event; // IE-ism

            // If pageX/Y aren't available and clientX/Y are,
            // calculate pageX/Y - logic taken from jQuery.
            // (This is to support old IE)
            if (event.pageX == null && event.clientX != null) {
                eventDoc = (event.target && event.target.ownerDocument) || document;
                doc = eventDoc.documentElement;
                body = eventDoc.body;

                event.pageX = event.clientX +
                    (doc && doc.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0) -
                    (doc && doc.clientLeft || body && body.clientLeft || 0);
                event.pageY = event.clientY +
                    (doc && doc.scrollTop  || body && body.scrollTop  || 0) -
                    (doc && doc.clientTop  || body && body.clientTop  || 0 );
            }
            window.cordX = event.pageX;
            window.cordY = event.pageY;

            // console.log(event.pageX+","+event.pageY)
            // Use event.pageX / event.pageY here
        }
    })();

    function eventClick(evt) {
        console.log("evt: ",evt);
        if (!window.cordsForAction){
            window.cordsForAction = {};
        };
        let epoch = Math.round((Date.now()/1000));
        console.log("clicked at: " + window.cordX + "," + window.cordY + " at location: " + window.location+ ", epoch: "+epoch);
        let cords = {"x": window.cordX, "y": window.cordY};
        if (window.cordsForAction[epoch]){
        }
        else{
            window.cordsForAction[epoch] = cords;
            sendMessageToExt("click", cords, epoch);
            delete window.cordsForAction[epoch];
        };
    }

    async function sendMessageToExt(actionType, cords, epoch){
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"type": "userAction" ,"action": actionType, cords: cords, epoch: epoch}, function (response) {
            if (response) {
                console.log("got a response");
                if (response.feedback) {
                    console.log("response.feedback:", response);
                }
            } else {
                console.log("no response from extension");
            };
        });
    }

    function setDocOnClickEvent(){
        window.cordsForAction = [];
        document.querySelectorAll("*").forEach((el)=>{ el.onclick = eventClick});
        console.log("setDocOnClickEvent");
    }

    function setChromeOnMessage(){
        console.log("setChromeOnMessage");
        chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
            function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
                console.log(sender.tab ?
                    "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                    "from the extension");
                if (request.type == "dataFromExtensionForPlay") {
                    console.log("got the message for dataFromExtensionForPlay, request.data: ",request.data);
                };
            });
    }

    function addRuntimeOnConnectListener(){
        console.log("addRuntimeOnConnectListener");
        chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(port => {
            console.log('connected ', port);
        });
    }

    addRuntimeOnConnectListener();
    setDocOnClickEvent();
    setChromeOnMessage();
```

Comment: The only built-in thing is `sender.frameId` in onMessage listener but what is "frame index" anyway and how exactly do you plan on using it? Also what if there are nested iframes?

Comment: In a given page with X iframes I would like to know the index of the iframe that I have a click in. As for nested iframes I don't know, I hope not to encounter such a case.

Comment: Assuming the click actives the iframe, you can do it in your content script for the main page itself (where window === top) by checking document.activeElement, then getting the index like [...document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')].indexOf(document.activeElement).

Comment: @wOxxOm your advice worked well, thanks for the help, you should add it as an answer so I could select it.